# Nginx: How to determine if a module is installed

Tags: nginx, geoip

Im using nginx as load balancer in a dockerized setup.
Im trying to get the [http_geoip_module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_geoip_module.html) up and running so I can redirect traffic based on users geographical position.

**Question:**

The command `nginx -V` outputs `--with-http_geoip_module=dynamic`.
Does this mean that the geoip_module is installed? Its the `=dynamic` that confuses me, this detail does not appear in the tutorials im following.

Comment: Where did you get your nginx from?

Comment: I guess you have to install `nginx-module-geoip` package. http://nginx.org/en/linux_packages.html#dynmodules

Comment: Official nginx image on docker hub:
https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx/

Comment: If I understand it correctly it's installed. https://github.com/nginxinc/docker-nginx/blob/master/mainline/jessie/Dockerfile You have to load this module with `load_module` directive.